# I have one json file of all products, and now I want to display only those products of current categories?

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, json

```
$baseUrl = $this->getBaseUrl();
$skinUrl = $this->getSkinUrl();
$currcategory = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory();
$products = file_get_contents('c_node.json');
$arr = json_decode($products,TRUE);
$temp = array_values($arr);

<ol class="product-grid">
<?php foreach ($temp as $product): ?>
    <?php
    $id = $product['entity_id'];
    $media = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
    $url = $product['url_path'];
    $small_image = $media.'catalog/product/'. $product['small_image'];
    $small_img_lable = $product['small_image_label'];
    $thumbnail = $media.'catalog/product/'. $product['thumbnail'];
    $name = $product['name'];
    $price = $product['price'];
    $special_price = $product['special_price'];
    $size = $product['size'];
    $imageUrl = $media.'catalog/product/'. $product['small_image'];
    ?>
    <li class="product-grid_item product-tile">
        <a class="product-image" href="<?php echo $url; ?>">
            <div class="quickview"><button class="button button--s button--inverted">Quick View</button></div>
                <picture class="pimg1">
                    <source srcset="<?php echo $small_image; ?>" media="(min-width: 400px)">
                    <img srcset="<?php echo $small_image; ?>" alt="<?php echo $small_img_lable;?>">
                </picture>
                <picture class="pimg2">
                    <source srcset="<?php echo $thumbnail; ?>" media="(min-width: 400px)">
                    <img srcset="<?php echo $thumbnail; ?>" alt="<?php echo $thumbnail;?>">
                </picture>
            <?php
            // GravDept:
            // Check if product is new.
            //$isNewProduct = Mage::helper('magefrontend')->isNewProduct($id);
            ?>
            <?php //if ($isNewProduct): ?>
                <!--
                <ul class="badge-list">
                    <li class="badge-list_item badge-list_item--new">
                        <?php// echo $this->__('New'); ?>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                -->
            <?php //endif; ?>
        </a>
        <?php
        $showMessage = false;
        if($size == 'XXL'){ // Use your option text to match
            $showMessage = true;
            break;
        }
        ?>
        <?php if($showMessage): ?>
            <div class="product-banner-box">
                <span class="plussize-banner">now in plus sizes</span>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

            <!--
            <div class="product-banner-box">
                <span class="plussize-banner">now in plus sizes</span>
            </div>
            -->

        <?php //if ($id->getRatingSummary()): ?>
            <?php //echo  ?>
        <?php //endif; ?>

        <?php //echo $this->getPriceHtml($product, true); ?>
            <div class="price-box">
                <?php if (!$special_price == 'null'):?>
                    <p class="old-price"> <span class="price-label">Regular Price:</span> <span class="price"><?php echo $price;?></span> </p>
                    <p class="special-price"> <span class="price-label">Special Price</span> <span class="price"> <?php echo $special_price; ?></span> </p>
                 <?php elseif($special_price == 'null'):?>
                     <span class="regular-price">
                        <span class="price"><?php echo $price;?></span>
                    </span>
                <?php endif;?>
            </div>

        <?php //if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()): ?>
            <a class="product-addwishlist" href="<?php //echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($product); ?>">
                <span class="trigger-icon icon-heart"></span>
            </a>
        <?php //endif; ?>

        <a class="product-name" href="<?php echo $url; ?>">
            <?php echo $name; ?>
        </a>
```

Observer:

```
public function productDataToJson(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $array = array();
    $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'thumbnail','size','price','special_price','url_path','thumb‌​nail','small_image',‌​'small_image_label')‌​)
        ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());

    foreach ($products as $_product) {
        $array[] = $_product->getData();
    }

    $jsonData = Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($array);
    file_put_contents("c_node.json", $jsonData);
}
```

Comment: Great you got ans :)

Comment: Need one more help, I want the json files of all category products, Means I want products json file as per categories.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '​' (T_STRING), expecting ')'  :(
@sv3n I getting this error, now i want multiple json file with category products as you suggest. but got this error :(

Comment: @sv3n need urgent help

Comment: Sorry, I'm busy today. As error says there seems to be a missing `)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want wo have only products from current category, you can try this in you observer code:

```
$array = array();
$category = Mage::registry('current_category');
# $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(41);
$products = $category->getProductCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'thumbnail', 'size', 'price', 'special_price', 'url_path', 'thumb‌​nail', 'small_image',‌ ​'small_image_label')‌​);

foreach ($products as $product) {
    $array[] = $product->getData();
}

$jsonData = Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($array);
# save json file for each category
file_put_contents('c_' . $category->getId() . '_node.json', $jsonData);
```

---

**Edit:**

You can add products category ids in your observer using `$_product->getCategoryIds()`:

```
foreach ($products as $_product) {
    $array[] = array_merge($_product->getData(), array('category_ids' => $_product->getCategoryIds()));
}
```

For you outp you can try something like this:

```
<?php foreach ($temp as $product): ?>
    <?php
    $catIds = $product['category_ids'];
    ...
    if (in_array(Mage::registry('current_category')->getId(), $catIds)) {
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Its not working, actually I want all products in json but along with its category ids

Comment: OK, then please add a better description to your question. Which event do you observe? What you need in detail?

Comment: If user add/update/delete product, json file needs to get updtaed with the product details, So that i will use this details on product listing page. But I category product listing page needs to be contain only that current category products.

Comment: Just to mention ... your code may work for small product catalog, but I guess on larger ones this may be not effective.

Comment: Okay, I got this. If any doubt, I will ask . Thnk you once agian. :)

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '​' (T_STRING), expecting ')' 
this gives me error :(

Answer (score 3):

Check like that in your json you will get `$_product->getCategoryIds()`.

Please write a condition like that

```
<?php foreach ($temp as $product): ?>
if (in_array($currcategory , $_product->getCategoryIds()) {
```

Hope it will helpful for you

Comment: My json is not getting category_id, How can I get this?

Comment: public function productDataToJson(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{ $array = array();
      $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
          ->getCollection()
          ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'thumbnail','size','price','special_price','url_path','thumbnail','small_image','small_image_label'))
          ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
      foreach ($products as $_product) {
          $array[] = $_product->getData();
      }
      $jsonData = Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($array);
      file_put_contents("c_node.json", $jsonData);
    }

Comment: This is my observer function. How can I get category id in it?

Comment: >joinField('category_id','catalog/category_product','category_id','product_id=entity_id',null,'left');
add this and get category id

Comment: Thanks but Where do I add this field?

Comment: before ->addstorefilter() in productdatatojson code

Comment: It gives me error, will you Please edit the code?
I opened quetion  -> [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45030642/how-to-get-product-category-id-in-json-in-magento]

Comment: okey i will check it

Comment: Did you get that?

Comment: i am looking i will place ans one finish

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61989/discussion-between-rama-chandran-and-sushant-thorat).

Comment: @RamaChandran +1 for right idea :) Sorry "stealing" this but i knew code from previous quesetion :)

Comment: @sv3n No problem ,  We are providing right right solution to Magento community and helping other. Thanks for vote :)

Answer (score 1):

```
  public function productDataToJson(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
  $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
  $tree = $category->getTreeModel();
  $tree->load();
  $ids = $tree->getCollection()->getAllIds();
  foreach ($ids as $id) {
    $array = array();
    $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($id)
        ->getProductCollection()
         ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
         ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
    foreach ($products as $_product) {
        $array[] = array_merge($_product->getData(), array('category_ids' => $_product->getCategoryIds()));
    }
    $jsonData = Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($array);
    # save json file for each category
    file_put_contents('c_' . $id . '_node.json', $jsonData);
  }
}
```

I solved this!! Thank You, If anything wrong, please suggest.