# How to fix Error: unexpected '​' (T_STRING), expecting ')' error?

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, json

How can I fix this error in my code:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '​' (T_STRING), expecting ')'
>   error

**Code**:

```
public function productDataToJson(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
  $array = array();
  $category = Mage::registry('current_category');
  # $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(41);
  $products = $category->getProductCollection()
      ->addAttributeToSelect('*'‌​);

  foreach ($products as $product) {
      $array[] = $product->getData();
  }

  $jsonData = Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($array);
  # save json file for each category
  file_put_contents('c_' . $category->getId() . '_node.json', $jsonData);
}
```

Comment: On which line ?

Comment: In my observer file, Actually I want to multiple json files of category products, once product saved, the json file of that category will update
please refer question ->https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/183215/how-can-i-create-multiple-json-files-of-category-products

Comment: in ->addAttributeToSelect('*'‌​);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code is OK ... but there seems to be a wrong encoded char.

Please type this manually again `->addAttributeToSelect('*');`

<sup>Had similiar problem with your code yesterday ... so make sure all files are correctly encoded `UTF8 w/o BOM`</sup>

Comment: Thank you @sv3n, I solved this
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/183027/i-have-one-json-file-of-all-products-and-now-i-want-to-display-only-those-produ?noredirect=1#comment253366_183027
I solved here, If Anything wrong, please suggest.

Comment: Not sure what you are doing ... :) Copy&Paste your code there http://phpcodechecker.com/ you'll get this error. Write this line manually (or at least `('*')`) and it works.

Comment: Hi @sv3n, I want all attribute lables instead of its id's in the json file, Please help ASAP.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/184505/how-to-get-attribute-lable-from-value-in-observer-for-creating-json-file-of-pro

Comment: @SushantThorat I try to help if I can and when I've time for it. Some questions are fast to answer, others take some more investigation ... If I do not answer I've either no time or no good idea. I read you question ... and i'll maybe answer later. Please remember ... I'm not getting payed for it, so dont worry I or someone else doesnt answer in time. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
public function productDataToJson(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
  $array = array();
  $category = Mage::registry('current_category');
  # $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(41);
  $products = $category->getProductCollection();
      //->addAttributeToSelect('*'‌​);

  foreach ($products as $product) {
      $array[] = $product->getData();
  }

  $jsonData = Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($array);
  # save json file for each category
  file_put_contents('c_' . $category->getId() . '_node.json', $jsonData);
}
```