# How to get attribute lable in observer, for creating json file of product details?

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, event-observer

```
public function productDataToJson(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
  $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
  $tree = $category->getTreeModel();
  $tree->load();
  $ids = $tree->getCollection()->getAllIds();
  $jsonFilePath = Mage::getBaseDir().'/jsondata';
  foreach ($ids as $id) {
    $array = array();
    $products = $category->load($id)
        ->getProductCollection()
         ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
         ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
    foreach ($products as $_product) {
        $array[] = array_merge($_product->getData(), array('category_ids' => $_product->getCategoryIds()));
    }
    $jsonData = Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($array);
    file_put_contents($jsonFilePath.'/c_' . $id . '_node.json', $jsonData);
  }
}
```

Currently I am getting attribute id's but not getting attribute lables.
eg. Color:23,Size:345. But I want Color:Red, Size : XL etc.

Comment: No..I want the product data in json file with its attribute and attribute lables.

Comment: This is my function in observer, i want to get json of all products details and attributes with its label.